# Не могу поймать элемент, после его создания

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеется такой код.
При изменении выбора элемента в `$("#jform_categories")` пытаюсь проверить существование скрытого поля с `id=#hidden-category` и если его нету, пытаюсь добавить его в форму.
Скрытое поле добавляется, но всегда, даже если оно туда уже добавилось в предыдущем ивенте.
Как решить данную проблему...

```
!(function() {

    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

        $("#jform_categories").chosen({



        }).change(function(event){
            if(event.target == this){

                var values = $(this).val();

                var form = $(this).closest('form');
                var element = $(form).find('#hidden-category');

                if (element.length > 0) {

                } else {

                    $('<input>').attr({
                        type: 'hidden',
                        id: '#hidden-category',
                        name: 'fieldname'
                    }).appendTo(form);

                }

            }
        });

    });

})();
```

Answer (score 3):

В атрибуте-то решетки не будет:

```
                $('<input>').attr({
                    type: 'hidden',
                    id: 'hidden-category', // !!!
```

Answer (score -3):

Так куда проще и слаще:

```js
$((){
    $('#jform_categories').chosen({}).change(({currentTarget})=>{
        // const values = $(currentTarget).val();

        const $forma = $(currentTarget).closest('form');

        if($forma.find('#hidden-category').length > 0)return false;

        $forma.append(`<input id="hidden-category" name="fieldname" hidden>`);
    });
});
```

Хз что это `.chosen({})`, как гугол говорит - *возможно вы имели ввиду* `.focus`

Не надо классов и +5 под авотаркой, просто возьми код и всо